# Newly installed Mathematica Message[$ConfiguredKernels::obso] is Protected error?

Tags: warning-messages

I installed Mathematica 13.3(My `$Version` result is `"13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2023)"` and I use Windows 10). Every time I open Mathematica, it will pop up an extra window showing the message:

```
SetDelayed::write: 
   Tag $ConfiguredKernels in $ConfiguredKernels /; 
     Message[$ConfiguredKernels::obso] is Protected.
```

The screenshot shows as follows
[image]

Everything seems to work fine(No code error when I use the functions inside the Mathematica) if I just ignore the error. But I want to know how can I fix this error?

Comment: Please inform WRI technical support.